# keeping pointer with single indirection operator as parameter pointing to multi dimentional array like arr[x][y][z]

Tags: c

I have this code that I am trying to understand,
it runs/works easily to print all elements of multi dimentional array

**Correct**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int *arr)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
}



int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print((int *)arr, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

but if my print function is something like this

**Wrong**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int **arr, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
}
```

and main like this

```
int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print(arr, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I get these warnings

```
pointers2.c:7:18: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    7 |         printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
      |                 ~^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |    |
      |                  int  int *
      |                 %ls
pointers2.c: In function ‘main’:
pointers2.c:14:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   14 |     print(arr, m, n);
      |           ^~~
      |           |
      |           int (*)[3]
pointers2.c:2:18: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[3]’
    2 | void print(int **arr, int m, int n)
```

I asked similar quetion sometime ago and someone mentioned that variable sized array can't be allowed in some computers' architecture but I could not locate the question on SO. So can anyone please elaborate what that means

Also if I have multi dimentional array in main then what are the other ways to handle them with array, can I use array of pointers, can someone please give me an example  of array of pointers to do the same shown in my correct example with example code

Comment: _`printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));`_ I don't see any previous mention of `n` in your function (first example). Plus you seem to be calling `print` with the wrong amount of args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way to pass an arbitrary size 2D array is to use Variable-Length array as parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int m, int n, int arr[m][n]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print(n, m, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

From C11, support for VLA and other Variably-Modified (VM) types was made optional. This decision was made to encourage some organization (read Microsoft) to make effort on improving compliance of their compilers (read MSVC) by reducing a number of features to implement, hoping that those optional features would be added in time. AFAIK, this initiative is considered a failure.

Comment: what if I dont know the size of array like dimention number. in a function I just want to do stuff to first element?

Comment: @user786, Can you explain? which is unknown `n` or `m`?

Comment: @user786, but the index to a scalar in 2D array must be a pair of integers. The index constructed as `idx = m * i + j` cannot be accessed `&arr[0][0] + idx` directly due to UB.

Comment: I think if this is proper way then this I should use

Comment: @user786 Are you asking how to pass an 2d array to a function without passing its dimensions as parameter? Just to able to access some `arr[i][j]` in this function?

Comment: Yes in function code I will keep predefined macros in loop for n and m

Comment: The `printf` in the loop should be `printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);` not `printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo,fixed, c&p error,thanks

Answer (score 1):

An `int(*)[3]` isn't an `int**`. You probably want an `int*` and you can get that by taking the address of the first element in your 2D array.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int *arr, int m, int n) {  // int*
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print(&arr[0][0], m, n);  // take the address of the first int in the array
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Accessing the inner array out of bounds makes your program have undefined behavior - but it'll *probably* work since the arrays must be contiguous in memory.

Comment: `You probably want an int* and you can get that by taking the address of the first element in your 2D array.` this sounds like memory is always of two D array like elements:`-0x...1->1, 0x..8->2,0x..12 ->3, ...` int is 4 hex values 1 to 4

Comment: technically speaking this code triggers UB, because `&A[0][0]` points to a first element of `A[0]` which is of type `int[3]`. Therefore `arr` parameter can be only accessed at indices from 0-2.

Comment: @tstanisl Yes, hence the Note at the end. It probably works anyway but it's technically UB.

Comment: @user786 I'm not sure I get your point. Yes the memory layout is like my answer assumes it to be in C.

Comment: right, but you could a new more words why it is UB.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `Yes the memory layout is like my answer assumes it to be in C` what about C++

Comment: @user786 C++ has the same row-major memory layout

Comment: @tstanisl I did mention that "_Accessing the inner array out of bounds ..._" makes the program have UB.

Comment: yes, just add information that the array that is accessed outside of its bound is `arr[0]` from `main` which type is `int[3]`. Thus `arr` parameter at be safely accessed at indices from 0 to 2

Comment: @tstanisl The pointer passed is to the first `int` in `arr[0]` so `arr[0]` is the _only_ array one can access in the function.

Comment: I know this, but it may not be obvious for less experienced readers